# Prove the family of function is compact & normal

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, normal-families

I have a problem with proving something.

I know that "a family $\mathcal{F}$ of function is called compact normal family
if the uniform limits of all sequences converging in $\mathcal{F}$ are themselves member of $\mathcal{F}$."

Here a family of functions $\mathcal{F}=\{ f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n \ |\ \ |a_n |\leq n \}$ defined in the disk of $|z|<1$  and  $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

I want prove this family $\mathcal{F}$ is compact normal.
I know that this family is normal because $|f(z)| \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |nz^n| $ and by Weistrass's M test, it's absolutely and uniformly converge and bounded. So, $\mathcal{F}$ is normal by Montel's theorem. 
But i can't about compact..

I can't understand 3 things.

1. What does this family's "sequences" look like?
2. At this time, how should we prove this sequence's uniform convergence?
3. Where should i start with the proof? I wish someone could give me a hint.

Comment: A sequence in $\mathcal F$ is what it should be i.e. a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathcal F$. So, you have functions $f_n \in \mathcal F$ i.e. $f_n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{kn}z^k$ where $|a_{kn}| \leq n$ for all $n$. You have to prove that for every such choice of $f_n$, there is a subsequence $f_{n_l}$ of $f_n$ that has a uniform limit. Then, you have to prove that the limit itself is a function that is in $\mathcal F$. To do this, you should focus on the coefficients, so start with the sequence $a_{k1}$, then look at $a_{k2}$. Think about where these coefficients lie, what that implies

Comment: in the 2nd line, you mean, $|a_{kn}| \leq k$ for all $k$, am i right?

Comment: Sorry, I mean $|a_{kn}| \leq k$, indeed, and start with the sequence $a_{1n}$, then $a_{2n}$, and so on.

Comment: I've been thinking about it. I got that $\{a_{1n}\}$ is a sequence of bounded compact set $|z| \leq 1$, so there's a convergent subsequence. And also $a_{kn}$ for all $k$. But it's hard to construct $f_n$ because it's infinite sum, so it is infinite dimension. I am stuck at this part.

Comment: That's actually the tricky part of the question, if anything. I'll leave you to figure out the rest, but it is a "subsequence of subsequence" type argument, in the sense : you get a subsequence of $a_{1n}$ that converges, say $a_{1n_k}$, to a point $b_1$. Now, take $a_{2n_k}$. Then, there is a subsequence of this that converges, say $a_{2n_{k_l}}$ to $b_2$. Now, see that both $a_{1n_{k_l}}$ and $a_{2n_{k_l}}$ converge to $b_1,b_2$ respectively . Can you see what to do with $a_3,a_4$ etc. now? You can do this and get a limit $b_3$. Use the $b_i$s to make a function.

Comment: Thanks for your great idea. I got it. One more question, at your first comment, you said that "you have to prove that for every such choice of $\{ f_n \}$, there is a subsequence $\{f_{nl}\}$ of $\{fn\}$ that has a uniform limit." But i think the way you proposed show that $f_{nl} \to f$, not $f_n \rightrightarrows f$. Am i right? if not, can you tell me how this proof is the proof of uniform convergence $f_n \rightrightarrows f$ ?